# best method to stop users posting urls

Tags: php

I am looking to implement a system to strip out url's from text posted by a user.

I know there is no perfect solution and users will still attempt things like:

www dot google dot com

so I know that ultimately any solution will be flawed in some way... all I am looking to do really is reduce the number of people doing it.

Any suggestions, source or approaches appriciated,

Thanks

Comment: Please be sure to, rather than strip the text, let the user know that you detected what looks like a website, and point out exactly what snippet you're referring to. Both having my text filtered without warning and extremely vague warnings annoy me greatly as a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of regular expression pattern matchers [here](http://www.regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=1&categoryId=2). Some of them are quite complex.
I would suggest that running multiple ones may be a good idea.

Comment: wow... really excellent website... I can never get my head around regular expressions. I think I will use this one:

([\d\w-.]+?\.(a[cdefgilmnoqrstuwz]|b[abdefghijmnorstvwyz]|c[acdfghiklmnoruvxyz]|d[ejkmnoz]|e[ceghrst]|f[ijkmnor]|g[abdefghilmnpqrstuwy]|h[kmnrtu]|i[delmnoqrst]|j[emop]|k[eghimnprwyz]|l[abcikrstuvy]|m[acdghklmnopqrstuvwxyz]|n[acefgilopruz]|om|p[aefghklmnrstwy]|qa|r[eouw]|s[abcdeghijklmnortuvyz]|t[cdfghjkmnoprtvwz]|u[augkmsyz]|v[aceginu]|w[fs]|y[etu]|z[amw]|aero|arpa|biz|com|coop|edu|info|int|gov|mil|museum|name|net|org|pro)(\b|\W(?<!&|=)(?!\.\s|\.{3}).*?))(\s|$)

Comment: which you can test with this link if anyone else is looking for such a regular expression

http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx?regexp_id=1016

Answer (score 0):

You need to define exactly what you want to strip out. The stricter the definition, the more false positives you will get. The following example will remove any string with 3 characters, followed by a period, more letters, another period and 2-4 more letters:

```
$text = preg_replace('/[a-z]{3}\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/i', '', $text);
```

The other end of strictness might be anything that ends on a period and 2-4 letters (like `.com`):

```
$text = preg_replace('/[a-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4}/i', '', $text);
```

Note that the latter will strip out the last word of a sentence, the full stop and the first word of the next sentence if someone forgets to add a space inbetween the sentences.

Comment: Hmm not great if it happened to be content related to programming (OP to confirm or not), as you'd likely end up getting rid of namespaces, package hierarchies and so on...